# history of the radius/diameter bound in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Anyone know the origin of the traditional bound, radius <= diameter <= 2radius?
Seems like something people have been discussing for ages, but I got curious and couldn't find the original source!

Comment: Perhaps, that would be the same person who introduced the notion of radius of a graph?

Comment: Isn't this bound trivial?  I mean, I guess somebody must have been the first to write it down, but I would guess later uses mostly came from noticing it independently.

Comment: Absolutely, yes, I imagine you're both right - it was presumably the first person to talk about radius and diameter in the same breath. As far as I know, Jordan introduced the center explicitly and radius implicitly in his 1869 paper, but he didn't (if memory serves) mention diameter or eccentricity at all. I don't know when/where those terms were formally defined.